# Catch Error in RetrofitError and pass it to RoboSpice Error

Tags: android, retrofit, robospice

I am using the Retrofit module provided by Robospice. I am making asynchronous retrofit calls. The problem is that if my call is unsuccessful I get a Retrofit Error but in robospice I am getting the the feedback in onSuccess and not in onFailure(RobospiceException).

I am using the following code to execute my webservice call.

```
mSpiceManager.execute(mProfileRequest, new ProfileRequestListener());
```

The loaddatafromnetwork call in ProfileRequest is as follows:

```
@Override
public Profile loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    initCountDownLatch();
    //Adding a retrofit callback.
    getService().getProfile("//profileid", new AbstractCallback<Profile>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Profile profile, Response response) {
            super.success(profile, response);
            ProfileRequest.this.profile = profile;
            mCountDownLatch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            super.failure(retrofitError);
            mCountDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
    mCountDownLatch.await();
    return profile;
}
```

Can anyone let me know how can Robospice see get onFailure ? In simple words has anyone tried implmenting robospice with retrofit "Asynchronous calls"(With Retrofit callback implemented") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should throw the [RetrofitError](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RetrofitError.html) in failure().

Comment: Throw it how? How will I catch the Retrofit Error in on @Override
        public void onFailure(final SpiceException spiceException) ?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to comment on @Snicolas's answer but I didn't have the rep points.

I believe what @Snicolas is saying is that if you throw the exception then RoboSpice will catch it and package it inside of a SpiceException.  You should be able to access the RetrofitError using the `getCause()` method:

`mySpiceException.getCause()`

and you can try throwing the RetrofitError like this:

```
@Override
public Profile loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    initCountDownLatch();
    RetrofitError myRetrofitError = null;
    //Adding a retrofit callback.
    getService().getProfile("//profileid", new AbstractCallback<Profile>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Profile profile, Response response) {
            super.success(profile, response);
            ProfileRequest.this.profile = profile;
            mCountDownLatch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            super.failure(retrofitError);
            mCountDownLatch.countDown();
            myRetrofitError = retrofitError;
        }
    });
    mCountDownLatch.await();
    if (null != myRetrofitError) {
        throw myRetrofitError;
    }
    return profile;
}
```

Also, why are you using the callback form of retrofit calls?  There are synchronous versions of retrofit calls so that you can do this:

```
@Override
public Profile loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    Profile profile = getService().getProfile("//profileid");
    ProfileRequest.this.profile = profile;
    return profile;
}
```

All you need to do is use Gson annotations on your Profile class so that Retrofit knows how to deserialize the server response.  Retrofit will automatically instantiate and configure a Profile instance.  Then you can just return it.  If Retrofit hits an error in this process it will throw the exception...then because you are not catching the RetrofitError, it bubbles up and gets packaged in a SpiceException as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks MattC and Stephan. I was previously using the Synchronous retrofit method. But I need to calculate the download speed and I wanted it to do it in a central way. Retrofit Response object gives the body length and the sent and received times. So its pretty easy to calculate download speed. But I do not get a Response method in Synchronous retrofit calls do I? Hence I changed my callbacks.

Comment: @SoH You actually can get exactly what you want!  Declare your synchronous methods with a return type of Response and you will get the raw Retrofit Response object.